# Update Plotly Fig Data after Fig.show() in Python

Tags: python, plotly, real-time

My goal is to run something (some optimization) in the background, and update the plot in the browser as the results are returned.

I follow the Plotly tutorial: 
https://plot.ly/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#the-update-traces-method

However, the last call is always `fig.show()`.
Calling `update_traces()` *after* `fig.show()` in Python has no effect in the browser.

This interaction should be driven by programatically (from Python), *not* by the user (via a button), as in here: 
https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/#restyle-button

Is it possible to do this? Is there some call like `fig.restyle()` I can call in Python that would trigger a redraw on the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also consider [Dash](https://dash.plot.ly/)...

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this would be in JupyterLab with the `FigureWidget` instead of a regular `Figure`.

Here are the relevant docs: https://plot.ly/python/figurewidget/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - I should have clarified I am not running my code in JupyterNotebook environment. Is this the only way to have the functionality I am asking for?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: Thanks - Dash looks interesting and could possibly work!

Comment: Whoops I had mean to add my Dash remark as a comment not an answer... ah well :)